# Libreoffice 6.1 w/ ubuntu 18.04 - menu bar "file" "tools" "edit" etc. has disappeared

Tags: gnome, 18.04, libreoffice

I Upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 recently, and when I did the menubar for libreoffice disappeared.  I also noticed that the menubar for Google-chrome also disappeared. I know that the update from 16.04 --> 18.04 changed from unity to gnome so perhaps this is an issue where I am just unfamiliar with where to locate the menubar in gnome windows.  Any help is appreciated as I've had major loss of productivity since my upgrade.

EDIT: I just checked and it appears that while google-chrome and libreoffice are missing the menu, other applications like pinta have a menu within the application window.  See screenshots.

Here is the Pinta screengrab. notice the menu in window.
[image: pinta screenshot]

Here is the libreoffice screengrab.  Notice the lack of menu in window.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The themes were messed in my case.

I installed the package `gnome-tweak-tool` to get a handle into the "tweaks" application. Further I changed the appearance theme to one that restores sanity.
Further I installed the package `gnome-themes-ubuntu`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-ubuntu
$ tweaks
```